# Best way to use AJAX navigation on website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am currently trying to use an AJAX type navigation for my website but there is so many way to do it and i don't know which of theses ways is the best.

In my head there is 2 main ways :

- Using Hash change on URL

This way is pretty simple but is it the best with history management? 
I find it a little confusing for users too.

- Using `window.history.pushState`

This way look very clean but here the probleme can be the referencing.

If you know a good tutorial (up to date) with the best practises for AJAX that would be awesome.

Comment: please use code for better explaination

Comment: Exactly what problem are you trying to solve? The correct choice of tool depends on the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: This is subjective question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only those 2 ways, then obviously use the 2nd option, since it's better for the users, and it has only benefits unlike the 1st option.

If you are open for other ways, then you should take a look at angular webapps and its built-in UI router. ( Easy tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router )